# How to set a sublink in react router

Tags: react-router

I am attempting to use react router to do a url like so:

```
example.com/admin/members/{anyid}
```

If this url is hit with the id it would display user info with that id.
My code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/auth" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/index" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I have attempted to do this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
  <Route path="/auth" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
  <Route path="/admin/members/:id" component={SavedMemberForm} />
  <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/index" />
</Switch>
```

My assumption was that `/admin/members/:id` would over ride any children urls in admin.  This is not the case when I hit `/admin/members/1234` it reads it as if I'm just going to `/admin`

How can I get it to achieve my desired result?

Comment: use [Dynamic Routing](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md), 
 something like `example.com/admin/members/:anyid`

Comment: I did see example the bottom one.  /:id